# C++ Nested Loop Assignment Issues

Tags: c++

I need help with this nested loop assignment. In this assignment you will develop a C++ program for a property management company that uses files and nested loops to write to a file and read from a file. The program will calculate total rent collected for the company, average rent collected per month for the company, display the highest grossing complex, and displays a warning message if zero rent was entered for any of the complexes.  So far I have the following, I don't know how I'm going to get highest entered complex this route.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("complexRents.txt");

    double months;
    double complexMain;
    double complexClay;
    double complexKing;
    double totalRent = 0;
    double averageRent;
    double highRent;
    double highestRent;
    double allAverage;
    int numComplex;
    int numMonths;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    cout << " How many complexes will you enter? ";
    cin  >> numComplex;
    cout << " How many months of rent will you input? ";
    cin  >> numMonths;

    for (int complex = 1; complex <= numComplex; complex++)
    {

        for (int rent = 1; rent <= numMonths; rent++)

        {
            double rentCost;
            cout << " Enter rent month " << rent << " for complex #" << complex                << "  : ";
            cin >> rentCost;
            totalRent += rentCost;
            highRent = totalRent;

        }
            cout << " " << highRent << endl; 
            cout << " " << endl;

    } 


    double totalMonths;
    totalMonths = numMonths * numComplex;
    averageRent = totalRent / totalMonths;
    cout << " Average rent = $ " << averageRent << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " Total rent collected = $ " << totalRent << endl;


    inputFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's very simple. First, take out a blank piece of paper and a pen. Write down in short, simple, logical sentences, your proposed algorithm for doing this. Then, [make an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck agrees that what you wrote down is correct, simply translate it into C++ code. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Oh thanks sorry i forgot this was not a forum to ask for help on coding...